# Is there a solution to find the external contour correctly in my images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour

I got a segmented image as entry in my program the goal is to split regions into two images one contains external contours(regions) and the other contains internal contours (regions).

Programme in python 3.7 and opencv 
I try to use some morphological operations (close) and smoothing filter (median) then I apply a binary and otsu threshold and canny edge detection to get a better version of contours with the fonction find contour
In first I extrac external contours with CV2.RETR_EXTERNAL but this is what I get:

```py
def function(image):
    #pretraitement
    im = cv2.imread(image,0)
     _Kernel = 3  
    iteration__ = 5
    im = Pretraitement.pretraitement.lissage_median(im, _Kernel, iteration__)
    kernel = (3,3)
    im = cv2.morphologyEx(im, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,kernel))

    high_thresh, im = cv2.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    lowThresh = 0.5 * high_thresh

    cv2.rectangle(im, (0, 0), (im.shape[1], im.shape[0]), 0, 3)
    contour = cv2.findcontours(
                        cv2.Canny(im.copy(), lowThresh, high_thresh),
                        Img_Colored_Readed.shape, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    MaskExtern = np.zeros((im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3),dtype=np.uint8)
    MaskRegion = np.zeros((im.shape[0],im.shape[1],3),dtype=np.uint8)
    MaskContour = = np.zeros(im.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(contour)):
                        for j in range(len(contour)):
                            #to check if the contour j is inside contour i 
                            if  BoundaryBasedDescriptors.Contours.pointInContour3(contour[i],contour[j]):
                                pass
                            else:

                                cv2.drawContours(MaskExtern,contour, j, (0,255,255), 1)
                        cv2.drawContours(MaskContour,contour,i,255,1)
                        cv2.drawContours(MaskRegion,contour,i,(255,i*10,255-i*10),-1)

                    cv2.imwrite('_external.jpg', MaskExtern)
                    cv2.imwrite('_contour.bmp', MaskContour)
                    cv2.imwrite('_colore.jpg', MaskRegion)
```

The link to the image represent the segmented image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSxN8.png)

and this is what I get when I draw all contours with thickness -1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzLql.jpg)

I expect to get the rigth external contour (regions) I get some regions that are internal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkNlX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
```python```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('cSxN8.png',0)
# treshold to create binary image
tr, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = thresh.copy()
# invert image
img_inv_ = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

#find_external_contours
_,cnt = cv2.findcontours(img_inv.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in cnt:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (127), 1)

#to extract the edges of the external contour
img = cv2.bitwise_xor(img,img_inv)
#binarisation of the external contour
_, img = cv2.threshold(img,126,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#now we fill the external region
cnt = cv2.findcontours(img_prete_2,cv2.RETR_CCOPM,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
mask_externe=np.zeros(img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(cnt.longeurCnt):
   cv2.drawContours(mask_externe,[cnt.contour [i]],-1,255,-1)

#get the internal region 
mask_internal = cv2.bitwise_xor(img_inv,mask_extern)


```
````

this is the complete solution (the approach is poposed by J.D.
    , thanks to you)

Answer (score 0):

This is the error in your code:
`cv2.rectangle(im, (0, 0), (im.shape[1], im.shape[0]), 0, 3)`
The result is assigned to nothing, so it does nothing. If you add `im =` in front you'll get the behavior you're expecting.

If your purpose is to separate the internal and the external white area's, you could also try this approach. First invert the image. Then find the external outline of the black area (in original, white in inverted), which you can then use as a mask to separate the area's. If necessary you you can use the the masked interior image to find the smaller contours.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('cSxN8.png',0)
# treshold to create binary image
tr, img = cv2.threshold(img,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# invert image
img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
# find external contours
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img_inv, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contours in gray
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(127),5)
# display image
cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It seems to be simple and quick I will try your solution and see what it will done